# Is it possible to Host an anvil app in Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, anvil

I'm trying to deploy my [anvil](https://anvil.works/) (web)app on Heroku...I don't know if it is possible or not.

so if it is possible then how do I configure my Procfile? How it should look like? and what more do I need?

after posting this question I've tried myself

**Procfile**

```
web: python hss.py
worker: python hss.py
```

after starting the deployment I got this error

```
File "/app/hssssss/hss.py", line 20, in <module>
 import anvil.server
 class LiveObjectProxy(anvil.LiveObject):
AttributeError: module 'anvil' has no attribute 'LiveObject'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a buildpack for anvil with heroku, but if there isn't then you can deploy on heroku with docker. You just have to provide a `Dockerfile` and a file called `heroku.yml`, then heroku will build the docker container for you.

Here are some links to help you with this :

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml

https://github.com/anvilproject/anvil-docker

https://anvil.works/articles/jupyter-docker-and-anvil

Comment: no ! there is no buildpack for the anvil. So I choose python (as buldpack )
and I deployed my app successfully. Now the problem is  it saying there is some internal errors like **AttributeError: module 'anvil' has no attribute 'LiveObject** though this problem wasn't on my PC, it's happening after deployment. 
I will try with docker now and let you know

Comment: I'm getting the same error in docker also **AttributeError: module 'anvil' has no attribute 'LiveObject'**  I don't know how to get rid of it. so please help me. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you installed anvil correctly in your Dockerfile, then I'm afraid this is an issue with anvil, which I can't help you with since I don't know anvil.